# How to define the parameter 'numDisparities' in StereoSGBM?

Tags: opencv, stereo-3d

I'm using StereoSGBM to get the 3D coordinates of one object. But I found that different value of numDisparities would change the matrix of disparity. For example, when I set numDisparities=64, the disparity of point A is 15. But when I set numDisparities=128, the disparity of point A is 30 or something. This will certainly change the result caculated by function cvReprojectImageTo3D. I want to figure out the relation between the parameter 'numDisparities' and the final matrix of disparity.

Answer (score 3):

`numDisparity` determines the resolution of your stereo / depth map. The levels of 'depth' that can be defined are driven by the value of your `numDisparity`. If your `numDisparity` value is higher it means that the resolution will be higher, meaning that more levels of depth will be defined. If it is lower it means the resolution will be lower, meaning that you may not be able to see many 'levels' of depth.

Increasing `numDisparity` makes the algorithm slower, but gives better results.